# Is OutputPath a required field in every PropertyGroup?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, finalbuilder

My projects appear to all have three `<PropertyGroup>` items.

One:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
```

Two:  `<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">` 
Three:  `<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">`

FinalBuilder has been failing. When I go into the project file and add `<OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>` to the first element in the .csproj file (an MSBuild file as I understand it), the build succeeds.

The remaining two elements already have `<OutputPath>` defined.

Is this a required field for all three elements? Why is it missing from the first element in my project files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When MSBuild compiles a project, it takes OutputPath as an argument, to where it should place the build output.

The .csproj file has some *default* settings. It's in the first <PropertyGroup>.

In the conditional `PropertyGroup`s, there are specific properties, to different configurations and platforms:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86' ">
```

Properties inside this node overwrites the default one, so it can specialize the build.

To hit the different `PropertyGroup`s, MSBuild takes some argument, for example, hitting "Release|x86", the command looks like this:

```
msbuild /p:Configuration="Release" /p:Platform="x86"
```

MSBuild will use the properties from the default `PropertyGroup`, and overwrite/use properties from the `PropertyGroup`s that meet the conditions, in this example "Release|x86" to compile the code.

Your problem sounds like MSBuild does not have the right arguments to evaluate the right `PropertyGroup`s.